# How do you install Intel video drivers for a Toshiba Satellite A665-S6086?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, intel-graphics, toshiba-satellite

Need help installing Intel video drivers on Ubuntu 11.10 for a Toshiba Satellite A665-S6086. Nothing is showing in Additional Drivers and there doesn't seem to be a whole lot on Google. I'm also fairly newbish with Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to install any video drivers for this computer. AFAIK this is an integrated i3 GPU and it should work out of the box in 11.10. If it doesn't then this is some kind of bug.

You can run this command to discover what driver are you running:

```
lshw -c video
```

There should be a line that this one:

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

That means that I'm using the i915 driver in my computer.

Why are you trying to install drivers?. Do you notice any problem?.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Intel's graphics drivers are open-source, so they can be included in a default install without any additional setup. More convenient than what you typically have to do to get NVIDIA or ATI graphics working, IMO.

Comment: Yes, but for a couple of not-really-Intel cards like the GMA500. AFAIK this laptop seems to use the i3 included GPU, so its drivers should be included by default.